# Turning on OSL breaks node material with Normal node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, osl

The following works with *Open Shading Language* unchecked in the *Render* panel

[image: OSL off]

but as soon as I check the *Open Shading Language* box, the material goes completely black. Adding an OSL script node in the same file work correctly so I have OSL set up correctly.

The problem appears to be with the *Normal* node, as feeding the *Normal* output of the *Geometry* node directly into the *Emission* node works whether OSL is on or off.

Blender 2.79

Comment: I get this, too, across to a 2018-08-06 build of 2.79..

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I’ve also replicated this - looks like a bug to me. Enabling/disabling OSL shouldn’t affect this node. Only option to work around would be to replicate the functionality another way - eg, Mapping node for the Normal output (rotating the normal) and Vector Math ‘Dot Product’ for the ‘Dot’ output (dot product of a vector and the incoming normal).

Comment: Thanks  for confirming the bug, I've filed a bug report. https://developer.blender.org/T56623